# rename multiple files using loop in batch script

Tags: batch-file, rename

Say, I have two folders named 0 and 1 in current directory and have 0.txt in folder 0 and 1.txt in folder 1. I want to rename both of them as test.txt using batch file. I have written the following one but

```
FOR /L %%A IN (0,1,1) DO (

 ren %%A\%%A.txt test.txt
 cd..
)
```

but only 0.txt has become test.txt in folder 0. Folder 1 file is unchanged. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: why `cd ..`? Delete it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

In a batch file:

```bat
@FOR %%A IN (0,1) DO @REN %%A\%%A.txt test.txt
```

Or using your original loop, *only useful for a sequence of four or greater*

```bat
@FOR /L %%A IN (0,1,3) DO @REN %%A\%%A.txt test.txt
```

On the command line:

```bat
FOR %A IN (0,1) DO @REN %A\%A.txt test.txt
```

and

```bat
FOR /L %A IN (0,1,3) DO @REN %A\%A.txt test.txt
```